# Could you please help me out this sentence?

Tags: sentence-meaning, there-is

I have recently read a sentence from *The Economist* magazine.

> Researchers there are rushing candidate vaccines into trials.

I don't understand, is there anything missing in this sentence? Why "there are rushing candidate vaccines into trials" right after the "Researchers"?

Comment: The subject here seems to be "Researchers there" = the researchers working somewhere.

Comment: Researchers are hurrying the progress of the vaccines.